# cv::bilateralFilter

Tags: qt, opencv

I am trying to implement bilateral filter using OpenCV in Qt. So far I have done this:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered() {
    QString fileName =
      QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Image"), ".",
                                   tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)"));
    image = cv::imread(fileName.toAscii().data());
    emit qtimage();
}
```

where `image` is of type `cv::Mat`. My filter function is:

```
cv::bilateralFilter(image, image, 0, 21, 3, 0);
QImage img = QImage((const unsigned char*)(image.data), 
                   image.cols,image.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);
QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(this->backgroundRole(), QBrush(img));
                 this->setPalette(palette);
```

But its giving a run time error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3) && src.type() == dst.type() && src.size() == dst.size() && src.data != dst.data)
    in bilateralFilter_8u, file C:\Downloads\Software\OpenCV-2.2.0-win\OpenCV-2.2.0\modules\imgproc\src\smooth.cpp, line 1282
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  C:\Downloads\Software\OpenCV-2.2.0-win\OpenCV-2.2.0\modules\imgproc\src\smooth.cpp:1282:
    error:    (-215) (src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3) && src.type() == dst.type() && src.size() == dst.size() && src.data != dst.data in function bilateralFilter_8u
```

Comment: Have you found any solution? Same problem occuring with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#bilateralfilter):

> This filter does not work inplace.

You have to create new image as a output from bilateral filter.

Comment: Hey @Cfr, I noticed that in the docs as well, however the function itself returns void in the source. Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: check out error message, possibly your output image has wrong size or type.

Comment: Creating new image is still not working, Have any idea?